# Prevent #content overlap with double sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap to create a webpage with 2 fixed sidebars, and a footer. I got the sidebars and footer positions appropriately, but having problems keeping the #content from overlapping the sidebars and footer.

**Objective:** The content width and height should shrink based on the sidebar width and footer height.

Example is here with Bootstrap JS: https://www.codeply.com/p/9SuDUCHCcA

HTML and CSS is below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

footer {
color: red;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  color: red;
}

#left-sidebar {
  left: 0;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

#right-sidebar {
  right: 0;
  min-width: 420px;
  max-width: 420px;
}


#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background: #011627;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

<nav id="left-sidebar" class="sidebar">
  <p>
  Banner
  </p>
  <p>
  Foo
  </p>
</nav>


<div id="content">
<h1 class="title">
Page title
</h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua

...

</div>
<nav id="right-sidebar" class="sidebar">
  <p>
  ToC
  </p>
  <p>
  Bar
  </p>
</nav>

<footer class="fixed-bottom">
  Fancy Footer  <br/><br/>
</footer>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the solution below in the Code snippet and made the Youtube video also.

Please check the below Youtube link for full tutorial:

https://youtu.be/TWdvIdmJcsU

Let me know the feedback :-)

```css
body{margin:0}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}
footer, .sidebar, #content{position:absolute;}
footer {
color: red;
bottom:0;
background:#000;
width:100%;
height:40px;
}

.sidebar {
  
}

#left-sidebar {
  left: 0;
  width:150px;
  top:0;
  background:#ccc;
  height:calc(100vh - 40px);
  z-index:1;
}

#right-sidebar {
  right: 0;
  width:150px;
  top:0;
  background:#ccc;
  height:calc(100vh - 40px);
}


#content {
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background: #011627;
  left:150px;
}
.content-wrapper{padding:15px;}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

<nav id="left-sidebar" class="sidebar">
  <p>
  Banner
  </p>
  <p>
  Foo
  </p>
</nav>


<div id="content">
<div class="content-wrapper">
<h1 class="title">
Page title
</h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua

...

</div>
</div>
<nav id="right-sidebar" class="sidebar">
  <p>
  ToC
  </p>
  <p>
  Bar
  </p>
</nav>

<footer class="fixed-bottom">
  Fancy Footer  <br/><br/>
</footer>

</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `position: fixed` will remove the sidebars from the natural flow of the elements (specifically removing it from effects of the flex container). A fixed element will not interact or push the elements around it.

You could instead try to center the `#content` div using side margins that match the widths of the sidebars.

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  color: red;
}

#left-sidebar {
  left: 0;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

#right-sidebar {
  right: 0;
  min-width: 420px;
  max-width: 420px;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 420px 0 300px; // center content between the sidebars
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background: #011627;
}
```

Comment: How about the footer? It doesn't seem to follow the same convention as the sidebars.

Comment: Adding margin to content which is 100%  is wrong solution. Then the content size will be 100% + left right sidebar width. because of this bottom horizontal bar will come which is again wrong. Sorry but I am not agreed with the solution. Please check my solution and I have made video also https://youtu.be/TWdvIdmJcsU

Comment: @AjayMalhotra You solution does not keep the sidebars fixed and the content area will not scroll once it gets taller than the screen.